Landau's Theoretical Minimum and Other Difficult Exam Problems and Solutions
I was wondering if anyone has compiled questions and solutions from Landau's legendary "Theoretical Minimum" exam or if there are any available translations of modern past exams.
Additionally, are there other notoriously difficult or famous physics exams at the undergraduate or graduate level that have been similarly documented, with problems and solutions?
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

This is the QM: http://people.tamu.edu/~abanov/QE/TM-QM.pdf
